# Angular component not re-evaluating when state changes in the NGXS store using the async pipe

Tags: angular, observable, ngxs

I am a bit confused as to why my PostListComponent is not re-evaluating the *ngIf statement when the state of my store changes when using the async pipe. I am using the postFacade to dispatch all of my actions. This is my PostListItem template:

```
`<section *ngIf="!postsFacade.isLoading$ | async else loading">
    <app-post-item 
        class="list-item" 
        *ngFor="let post of postsFacade.posts$.posts | async; index as i" 
        [post]="post"
        [index]="i">        
        <img [routerLink]="['movies', i]" class="movie-card-image" src="../../../../../../../assets/images/movie_img_placeholder.jpg" alt="Movie Placeholder Image"
        (click)="moviesFacade.fetchMovieDetails(i);">
    </app-post-item>       
</section>

<ng-template #loading>
    <app-loader></app-loader>
<ng-template>`
```

When fetching posts and the server is on standby the loading spinner displays correctly, however when all of the posts are fetched it does not go away, indicating that the async pipe is not re-evaluating the isLoading$ property.

My HomeComponent on ngOnInit => this.postsFacade.loadPosts. My PostsFacade looks like this 
`

```
export class PostsFacadeService {
  public posts$: Observable<Post[]> = this.store.select(state => state.posts.posts)
  public isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(state => 
  state.posts.loading);
  constructor(private store: Store) {  }

  public loadPosts(): void{
    console.log("Dispatching FetchPosts from PostsFacadeService");      
    this.store.dispatch(new actionTypes.FetchPosts());
  }

}
```

`

And in NGXS here is my fetchPosts action

```
`
    @Action(actions.FetchPosts)
    fetchAll(ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>){
      console.log("fetching all posts");
      ctx.patchState({...ctx.getState(), loading: true})
        return this.postService.fetchPosts().pipe(
        switchMap((postsRequest) => {
          // we are using switchMap in this case, because we want to subscribe to the current observable and unsubscribe from it if another request is coming in to get all posts
          console.log("Inside of switchMap. Dispatching posts success")
          return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsSuccess(postsRequest))
        }),
        retryWhen(errors => {
          return errors
                  .pipe(
                    delayWhen((error, i) => 
                    {
                      if(i != 3){
                        console.log(`Sometheing went wrong connecting to the server. Retrying 3 times. Attempting: ${i + 1}...`);
                      }
                      return iif(() => i + 1 >= 4,
                       throwError(error),
                       timer(2000)
                      )
                    })                    
                  );
        }),
        catchError(err => 
        {
          // Return user friendly error message
          console.log("Displaying user friendly error message", err)
          ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsFail(err))
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log("An error occured. Returning empty collection");
          return of([]);
        })
        )
        .subscribe(
          res => console.log("HTTP response", res),
          err => console.log("HTTP Error", err),
          () => console.log('HTTP request completed')
        )
    };
`
```

What am I missing that even though the console shows the loading property to be set back to false (which is done inside the FetchPostsSuccess action) my PostListsComponent is still thinking its loading posts. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxh1sr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: is this the important takeaway ? asap.schedule(() => this.store.dispatch(new LoadZoosInCountry('USA'))); The schedule method?

Comment: When are you setting the loading back to `false`? It's not included in the code and is the most obvious answer on this one. You could try to add it where `console.log('HTTP request completed')` is currently.

Comment: I am setting it back to false inside of the `return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsSuccess(postsRequest))`. So when I inspect the state after the request finishes, its already set to false, but for some reason the state is not picked up by my component.